# Add values from one csv to another

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have 2 csv files like this:

```
csv1 = `id,grade,gpa
1,42,2
1,44,2
1,52,2
1,62,2
2,65,3 
3,17,2`;

csv2 = `id,status
2,yes
1,no
3,no`;
```

I read the csv like this:

```
  d3.queue()
     .defer(d3.csv, "csv1.csv")
     .defer(d3.csv, "csv2.csv")
  .await(function(error, data, data2) {...}
```

And convert them:

```
 data.forEach(function(d) {
 d.id = d.id;
 d.grade = +d.grade;
 d.gpa = + d.gpa;

 });

 data2.forEach(function(d) {
 d.id = d.id;
 d.status = d.status;
 });
```

I want to add the value "status" from the second csv to the first csv according to the id...

something like this

```
 [{
  "id": "1",
  "grade": "42",
  "status": "no"
  },
  {
  "id": "1",
   "grade": "44",
  "status": "no"
  },....]
```

To do this I try something like this but I get the following error message

```
data1.forEach(function(d) {
var obj = data2.find(function(e) {
return d.id === e.id
});
d.status = obj.status;
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Status' of undefined

Any idea why?

Comment: First please `console.log(obj)` and tell us what it logs

Comment: Please  post your data objects and console of the error.

Comment: @Attersson return the new values and suddenly Uncaught TypeError...maybe because the the length from csv1 is different from the csv2?

Comment: @amrendersingh {id: "503e6046cdd93b3fb70d6a6b038bce83",grade: 2, status …} ...and at the end  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu what if there is no object with given id in data2?

Comment: @CatalinVasilescu and ycould you also post console.log(d) ?

Comment: @amrendersingh you are right... i think that the problem is that sometimes there is no object with given id in data2...any idea how I can solve this?

Comment: @Attersson yes..the same values and after Uncaught TypeError:

Comment: If a check, as in the accepted answer, fixed it, how is it possible that console.log actually logs the correct values and it gives the error? I would have expected it would not log the correct property. If the accepted answer works, then there is something definitely off with the logging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that there is no check, that the obj is found in data2 or not.Try the following:

```
data1.forEach(function(d) {
  var obj = data2.find(function(e) {
   return d.id === e.id
  });
  if(obj)
   d.status = obj.status;
});
```